# Error when starting treesheets

Tags: apt, 16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. When I run TreeSheets this window appears:

[image]

I ran

```
sudo apt-get purge treesheets

sudo apt-get install treesheets

treesheets
```

but I still get the same error.

The program still works fine, I just have no idea what this error report is even trying to tell me. What is wxDisplay and what is an invalid index? Does it suggest a general problem with my system or is it just isolated to this particular program?

Comment: Seems like a bug with the program. You should save the backtrace to a file and pass it on to the devs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can't reproduce this problem locally, but it appears to be multiple display related, and I made a pre-emptive fix for it: https://github.com/aardappel/treesheets/commit/870c780433445d4f645418315b653c80fd0d129d

(note: you'll get quicker response to bugs if you post directly on github).